# Como ordenar do que tem mais registros ao que tem menos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho uma tabela aonde será armazenada `id_produto` e `ip` . Irei montar um "módulo" aonde o sistema irá puxar alguns dos produtos que tiveram mais visitas, então o que preciso fazer é puxar os produtos que tem mais registros na tabela, do maior ao menor. Como posso fazer isso utilizando o PHP / MySQL ?

Comment: Quais são as tabelas que tem? O número de visualizações do produto corresponde ao número total de pedidos ao recurso do produto, Ou corresponde ao número de utilizadores diferentes que viram o produto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `count()`.

Dessa forma seria assim:

```
SELECT *, count(ip) AS contagem
FROM tabela
GROUP BY id_produto
ORDER BY contagem DESC
```

Dessa forma você irá contar o `ip`, declarando o nome de 'contagem'.
O número de `ip` por `id_produto` será ordenado em `DESC`, além disso você poderá mostra-lo uma vez que está no `SELECT`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nossa amigo sua pergunta foi um pouco ampla, mas criei um select que vai te ajudar.
Pensando em uma estrutura que você teria duas tabelas

- **produtos** (id_produto, nome, descricao, etc)
- **produtos_visualizados** (id_produto, ip)

Este select retorna os produtos pela ordenado pelo numero de visualizações DESC

```
SELECT produtos.*, count(produtos_visualizados.*) AS visualizacao 
FROM produtos
left join produtos_visualizados ON produtos.id_produto = produtos_visualizados.id_produto
group by produtos.id_produto
order by visualizacao DESC
```

Agora você so tem que inserir nessa tabela toda vez que um produto for acessado, e criar uma model para recuperar estes dados.

Answer (score 0):

No SQL, para você trazer esses "alguns produtos", primeiro você precisa definir quantos serão, no exemplo abaixo, considerei os top 10:

```
SELECT prd.id_produto,
       rel.ip 
       COUNT(prd.id_produto) AS total_produtos
FROM TABELA_PRODUTO prd
INNER JOIN  TABELA_REL_PRODUTO_TOTAL rel on(rel.id_produto=prd.id_produto)
GROUP prd.id_produto ORDER BY total_produtos desc LIMIT 0,10;
```

Agora se nessa tabela relacional, terá a contagem diretamente, teria que ser algo assim:

```
SELECT prd.id_produto,
       rel.ip, 
       rel.total
FROM TABELA_PRODUTO prd
INNER JOIN TABELA_REL_PRODUTO_TOTAL rel on(rel.id_produto=prd.id_produto)
GROUP prd.id_produto ORDER BY rel.total desc LIMIT 0,10;
```